# Choropleth map - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, geojson, choropleth

I get **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'** when I tried to do a Choropleth map. What went wrong?

**Error**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-15d9491e7d8a> in <module>()
     25     fill_opacity=0.7,
     26     line_opacity=0.2,
---> 27     legend_name='Lorem Ipsum'
     28 ).add_to(Toronto_map)
     29 # display map

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/folium/features.py in get_by_key(obj, key)
    993             def get_by_key(obj, key):
    994                 return (obj.get(key, None) if len(key.split('.')) <= 1 else
--> 995                         get_by_key(obj.get(key.split('.')[0], None),
    996                                    '.'.join(key.split('.')[1:])))
    997 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**My attempt at Choropleth map**

```
threshold_scale = np.linspace(df['Percent'].min(),
                              df['Percent'].max(),
                              12, dtype=int)
threshold_scale = threshold_scale.tolist() # change the numpy array to a list
threshold_scale[-1] = threshold_scale[-1] + 1 # make sure that the last value of the list is greater than the maximum immigration

#  download countries geojson file

!wget --quiet https://...some path../world_countries.json

world_geo = r'world_countries.json' # geojson file

# create map and display it
Toronto_map = folium.Map(location=[43.653963, -79.387207], zoom_start=12)

# generate choropleth map 
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=world_geo,
    data=dfC,
    columns=['location', 'Percent'],
    key_on='Feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Lorem Ipsum'
).add_to(Toronto_map)
# display map
Toronto_map
```

**My data `dfC` structure** with 12 rows in total

```
location    Ethnic  Percent lat lng
0   Beaches-East York   Canadian , English , Scottish   21.0    43.681470   -79.306021
```

**Copy and Paste part of the geojson file here**

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Canada"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-63.6645,46.55001],[-62.9393,46.41587],[-62.01208,46.44314],[-62.50391,46.03339],[-62.87433,45.96818],[-64.1428,46.39265],[-64.39261,46.72747],[-64.01486,47.03601],[-63.6645,46.55001]]],[[[-61.806305,49.10506],[-62.29318,49.08717],[-63.58926,49.40069],[-64.51912,49.87304],[-64.17322,49.95718].....[-70.665765,83.169781],[-68.5,83.106322]]]]},"id":"CAN"},
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update your question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks. Added the full error msg. Was that what you refer to?

Comment: Well if you get such an error it likely means that the object you have referenced does not exist. Try checking to see whether your Chloropleth map got saved to your desired location.

Comment: @SVengat I don't understand what do you mean by saving to desired location?

Comment: As in, your value did not get saved to a variable. Maybe you used a method that only modifies an object and does not return any value. Therefore in your variable, "None" gets saved instead of your value.

Comment: still couldn't get it work. Anyone can help with this?